# Disable $keyword$ expansion by RCS ci check in?

Tags: vim, vi, cvs, rcs

For better or worse, I am using rcs to track changes to HTML and JSON files exported from chatGPT.  Some of these contain chats with embedded $keyword$'s.  These get expanded on ci check in.  How do I disble this without stepping on these files?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, RCS [and CVS](https://www.gnu.org/software/trans-coord/manual/cvs/html_node/Avoiding-substitution.html) never had an option to *fully* disable all keyword processing (at least I couldn't find that in the source code), but if you use the `cvs -ko` or `cvs -kb` option during checkout, it will "generate a keyword identical to the original". This behavior can apparently be set as default for each file using `rcs -ko`.

Answer (score 0):

Took a sledge hammer approach: converted the files to hex encoded text, then checked them in:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in  ../html/*.* ; do to=`basename $i` ; ls -d ../html/$to ; xxd -p $i ../rcs/$to.hex ; done
touch ../html/rcsLog.txt
cp ../html/rcsLog.txt ../rcs
ci -r -q -mnull -t-null ../rcs/*.hex
ci -l -q -mnull -t-null ../rcs/rcsLog.txt
```